# Django: How would you constantly check an API even when web app is not loaded?

Tags: python, django

My website needs to send an email to users even when the web app is not running.

I have an API and each time I receive data I need to send my users an email.

I need to be guided to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered writing a python script and letting it run on your server, totally separate from django?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a scheduler, https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler may an option for you.